# How to integrate word processor features into a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf

The application I'm developing is build around a user that can have text documents. These documents are stored into a SQLite database as blobs. The application is standalone and a requirement is an installation as simple as "Next-Next-Finish".

I'm looking for how to allow the user to write rich text inside the application. The ideal solution would be to embed a text processor (such as Word or OpenOffice) inside my WPF application.

How did you resolve this kind of problem in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in RichTextBox responds to built-in "EditingCommands" commands, such as EditingCommands.ToggleBold, EditingCommands.ToggleItalic etc.  so you could write your own. There's a ton of docs out there for this approach. A couple examples are below:

- http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34644
- http://elegantcode.com/2010/10/26/create-your-own-format-bar-for-the-wpf-richtextbox/

Now, in my limited experience with the WPF richtextbox, this is more of a pain sometimes than it is worth.  So really I think it would come down to your resources. If you have the development time, it might be worth it to code it up yourself. But, if you have money to spend and you need something stable quickly,  I'd most definitely go with an existing 3rd party library.

one of the libraries that we use is Actipro, though I haven't messed around too much with their Editors. They have a trial, so you could check it out.

- http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/wpf/wpfstudio/LiveDemo/SampleBrowser.xbap

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I wanted a few more features but I don't have a lot of development time. RichTextBox's a good deal

Answer (score 1):

TX Text Control is one way - they've got a free edition for WinForms though the WPF version has a relatively big price attached.

You could try hosting the WinForms control inside your WPF app though it's obviously not as clean a solution as using a native WPF control